# k-means clustering mapping

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using K-Means clustering of sklearn and want to replace the computed K-Means cluster labels with the centroid values using trained K-Means model.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
# Initialize K-Means clustering model-
kmeans_conv1 = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)

# Train model on training data (compute k-means clustering)-
kmeans_conv1.fit(conv1_nonzero.reshape(-1, 1))

# number of clusters used-
kmeans_conv1.n_clusters
# 5

# Get centroids-
kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_
'''
array([[-0.05669265],
       [ 0.06742188],
       [-0.08835593],
       [ 0.03749201],
       [ 0.0896403 ]], dtype=float32)
'''


# Clustered labels of each data point-
kmeans_conv1.labels_

set(kmeans_conv1.labels_)                                             
Out[142]: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

# Get clustered label for each data point-
clustered_labels = kmeans_conv1.labels_
```

Currently, I am using if-else conditions to map the labels to the centroid values as:

```
new_clusters = []


for clabel in clustered_labels:
    if clabel == 0:
        new_clusters.append(kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[0][0])
    elif clabel == 1:
        new_clusters.append(kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[1][0])
    elif clabel == 2:
        new_clusters.append(kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[2][0])
    elif clabel == 3:
        new_clusters.append(kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[3][0])
    elif clabel == 4:
        new_clusters.append(kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[4][0])
```

At the end, I want 'new_clusters' list or np.array variable to contain the centroid values instead of the cluster labels.

However, is there a better way to achieve this without using if-else conditions?

Comment: Will your centroids always be of length 1? Will you be working with more than 1 feature (i.e. your centroid will then become an array of length >1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sufficient:

```
for clabel in clustered_labels:
    new_clusters.append(
        kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[clabel][0]
    )
```

Comment: the first method gives `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1' while the second method just maps the cluster labels to the centroids. I don't want this. What I want is for 'new_clusters' list variable/np.array to contain the centroid weights INSTEAD of the cluster labels! I used a list and not a dict because I want the centroid values in place of cluster labels.

Comment: So essentially you are making a copy of the `kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_` array, but with only values?

Answer (score 0):

Found this method:

```
# First conv layer condition-
cond_conv1 = [clustered_labels == 0, clustered_labels == 1, clustered_labels == 2, clustered_labels == 3, clustered_labels == 4]

# values-
val_conv1 = kmeans_conv1.cluster_centers_[:, 0]

# Get new clustered value weights-
new_weights_conv1 = np.select(cond_conv1, val_conv1)
```